# Issue: Google/apiclient 2.1.0 for authorization

Tags: php, composer-php, google-api-client

I am using google/apiclient 2.1.0 version for authorization and my php version is 7.0.33 and i am facing version issue.

> composer detected issues in your platform: your composer dependencies require a php version >= 7.1.0

Can anyone suggest which version goes with php 7.0.33.

I tried with different version but it shows same error!!

Comment: Not sure WDYM. Either you use or you can’t install due to version mismatch. I assume you would “like to use”, but cannot install the package. Update your question with the output of `composer why-not google/apiclient`

Comment: @emix its says `there is no installed package depending on google/apiclient in versions not matching 2.1.0`